# Do I need to seed first before I use EVP to signal in the Openssl?

Tags: c++, openssl

When I see [the document of Openssl](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/EVP_SignInit.html), I noticed taht:

> When signing with DSA private keys the random number generator must be
>   seeded or the operation will fail. The random number generator does
>   not need to be seeded for RSA signatures.

So, wether it means that when I use `EVP_SignInit` to signature the data by ECDSA, I need to seeded first?

It the answer is right, what should I do?

My `Sign()` code is:

```
bool Sign::EC_sign(const std::string &msg, std::string &str_sign_dgst,
                   SignatureScheme sign_scheme) {

  EVP_MD_CTX *md_ctx;
  md_ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
  if (md_ctx == NULL) {
    return false;
  }

  if (md_ctx_sign_init(sign_scheme, md_ctx) != 1) {
    return false;
  }

  if (EVP_SignUpdate(md_ctx, (unsigned char *)msg.c_str(), msg.length()) != 1) {
    return false;
  }

  unsigned int slen;

  char *uc_sign_dgst = (char *)malloc(EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE);
  if (EVP_SignFinal(md_ctx, (unsigned char *)uc_sign_dgst, &slen, key) != 1) {
    return false;
  }

  EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(md_ctx);

  str_sign_dgst = std::string(reinterpret_cast<char *>(uc_sign_dgst));
  cout << str_sign_dgst << endl;
  cout << "str_sign_dgst:" << str_sign_dgst.length() << endl;
  return true;
}
```

My `Veri()` code is:

```
bool Sign::EC_veri(const std::string &msg, std::string &str_sign_dgst,
                   SignatureScheme sign_scheme) {
  EVP_MD_CTX *md_ctx;
  md_ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
  if (md_ctx == NULL) {
    return false;
  }

  if ((md_ctx_veri_init(sign_scheme, md_ctx)) != 1) {
    return false;
  }

  if (EVP_VerifyUpdate(md_ctx, (unsigned char *)msg.c_str(), msg.length()) !=
      1) {
    return false;
  }

  int ret;
  ret = EVP_VerifyFinal(md_ctx, (unsigned char *)str_sign_dgst.c_str(),
                        str_sign_dgst.length(), key);
  EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(md_ctx);
  cout << "EC_veri EVP_VerifyFinal(): " << ret << endl;
  if (ret != 1) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago seeding the OpenSSL random number generator could be a problem. These days, assuming you are on some relatively modern mainstream OS and a currently supported version of OpenSSL, it just isn't. There could be issues on certain platforms with restricted access to entropy (e.g. an embedded device) - but for most users this concern doesn't apply.

The OpenSSL RNG will seed itself automatically. If in the unlikely event that it is unable to do so then any operation requiring random data will just fail. In other words you can just do your sign operation - if it succeeds then there was enough entropy available.

Comment: Thanks for your help!